# How to make UITextView selectable in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have this UITextView in Swift:

```
let contactText = UITextView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,200,50))
contactText.selectable = true
contactText.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypes.Link
contactText.userInteractionEnabled = true
contactText.editable = false 
contactText.text = "Some text goes here and some website here www.google.com"
self.view.addSubview(contactText)
```

I want to be able to double tap or tap and hold to select the text and then give the user the option to select all or copy (just like most apps do). The above code didn't work although it seems like it should, is there another way of doing it?

EDIT:

The above code actually works, the reason why is not working (not 100% sure yet) is probably because the UITextView is within a UIView that has a PanGestureRecognizer attached to it, so maybe that is blocking it? any ideas?

Comment: Your code worked for me as well. You might have to make the pan gesture recognizer on the view fail when the gesture recognizer on the textView occurs

Comment: Yep, works for me too. Going off of what Bluehound said, specifically look into 
`gestureRecognizer:shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer:` https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate/gestureRecognizer:shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer:

Answer (score 4):

To make a UITextView selectable you only need to add these two lines:

yourTextView.selectable = true

yourTextView.userInteractionEnabled = true

Comment: In Swift 5: `yourTextView.isSelectable = true` and `yourTextView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true`. However both these are true by default. So there is no need to explicitely set it.